# Aligning items in a card

Tags: html, css

Here, I am display all the user bookings. It looks okay until the equipments requirement is long and it messes up my alignment. How can I change it so that the card grows bigger vertically and my other fields are not affected.

[Image showing the bookings and the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r29GZ.png)

I tried changing flex to 1. Instead of the text expanding horizontally, I think it would look better if it expanded vertically (justify)

```css
.card {
  display: ruby-text;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card-column {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 120px;
}

.card-value {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Booking ID:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[0] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Room:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[1] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">User:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[2] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Date:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[3] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Time:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[4] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Attendance:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[5] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Equipment</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[6] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-column">Status:</div>
    <div class="card-value">{{ booking[7] }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-item">
    <button onclick="updateBooking('{{ booking[0] }}')">Update</button>
    <button onclick="deleteBooking('{{ booking[0] }}')">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use  `<table>` ?

Comment: Indeed, this is tabular data and *should* be in a `table`. Then you can set fixed widths with `table-layout: fixed`.

Comment: Its harder to make tables look nicer, that was my only concern

Answer (score -1):

You should set `max-width` and `text-wrap` for your column which has contain long content of your table.